# How to split pdf document based on patch-t page? Using Aspose? Or if any best suitable?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, document, aspose.pdf

I have a pdf document which includes patch-t page for every 3 pages.
I want to split pdf document based on patch-t. Using aspose I saw there is a provision where I can print patch-t in pdf.
 Is it possible to split based on patch-t using Aspose? If not, what is the best suitable library for my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Here the link that shows how to print pdf with patch-t

https://docs.aspose.com/display/barcodejava/How+to+Generate+a+Patch+Code

Comment: If you `know` it is every third page, then you could use the command line utility with `PDFSplit -split 3`. https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html

Comment: We will not know that. For example, I used page 3.

Comment: So you're also searching for a patch code detector library. Aspose can do it in .net https://blog.aspose.com/2014/09/11/improved-recognition-of-pdf417-macropdf417-qr-and-patchcode-barcodes-using-aspose.barcode-for-.net-6.5.0/ it is unclear if they can in java. (PDFBox cannot). But if you're an Aspose client, then you should have access to support...

Comment: Do we have any other java libraries that suites this requirement?

Comment: No, all I did was a google search. This site is for programming, not to choose software. Use https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for that.